# how to highlight XML tags in text-area writer

Tags: html, xml

```
<div class="box-body">
<div class="form-group">
<label class="control-label">
<?php echo trans('site_key'); ?></label>
<textarea name="create-xml-header" id="create-xml-header" rows="1" cols="100"> </textarea>
</div>          
</div>
```

output:
[output text area](https://i.stack.imgur.com/eUv9Y.png)

how to highlight XML tags in this text-area writer ?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can use a syntax highlighting library or plugin to highlight XML tags in a text-area writer. One popular library is CodeMirror. You can find multiple examples of how to use CodeMirror with XML on the official website.

For example, you can use the following code to enable XML syntax highlighting in your text-area writer:

```
<script>
  var editor = CodeMirror.fromTextArea(document.getElementById("create-xml-header"), {
    mode: "xml"
  });
</script>
```

Comment: I found this: https://github.com/codemirror/codemirror5  but I need to install on server? Can I call  url to  plugin in <script  url ? if yes what url should be called? because I not see this in github

Comment: Yes, you can call the URL to the plugin in a <script> tag. The GitHub page for CodeMirror 5 also provides instructions for installing the plugin on a server.